# Парсинг объектов с ключами, с помощь JsonReader

Tags: java, android

Возникла проблема с парсером JSON с помощью класса JsonReader (JSON приложен ниже, а так-же код парсера). Получается что первый элемент он читает хорошо, а вот на втором элементе получаю исключение:

> W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a name but was BEGIN_OBJECT
>   W/System.err:     at android.util.JsonReader.nextName(JsonReader.java:390)
>           at ua.com.lacharme.sdk.FloristList.readData(FloristList.java:20)
>           at ua.com.lacharme.sdk.Api.getFloristList(Api.java:136)
>   W/System.err:     at ua.com.lacharme.QRScanerActivity$1$1$1.run(QRScanerActivity.java:114)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

**JSON**

```
{
"0": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Внештатный флорист",
    "phones": "000",
    "is_active": "0",
    "worker_type_id": "2",
    "created_at": "2018-06-19 08:04:45",
    "updated_at": "2018-12-22 14:46:31",
    "pivot": {
        "partner_id": "1",
        "worker_id": "1"
    }
},
"2": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Александра",
    "phones": "5445",
    "is_active": "0",
    "worker_type_id": "2",
    "created_at": "2018-09-13 23:50:32",
    "updated_at": "2018-12-25 14:35:20",
    "pivot": {
        "partner_id": "1",
        "worker_id": "3"
    }
},
"8": {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Ирена",
    "phones": "+45544",
    "is_active": "1",
    "worker_type_id": "2",
    "created_at": "2018-10-30 11:53:56",
    "updated_at": "2018-10-30 11:53:56",
    "pivot": {
        "partner_id": "1",
        "worker_id": "9"
    }
},
"9": {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Олеся",
    "phones": "+45545",
    "is_active": "0",
    "worker_type_id": "2",
    "created_at": "2018-12-07 14:31:13",
    "updated_at": "2019-01-10 13:55:51",
    "pivot": {
        "partner_id": "1",
        "worker_id": "10"
    }
},
"10": {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Марина",
    "phones": "+45545",
    "is_active": "1",
    "worker_type_id": "2",
    "created_at": "2018-12-16 18:45:53",
    "updated_at": "2018-12-16 18:45:53",
    "pivot": {
        "partner_id": "1",
        "worker_id": "11"
    }
},
"11": {
    "id": 12,
    "name": "Наталья Бабич",
    "phones": "55565",
    "is_active": "1",
    "worker_type_id": "2",
    "created_at": "2018-12-20 11:22:35",
    "updated_at": "2018-12-20 11:22:35",
    "pivot": {
        "partner_id": "1",
        "worker_id": "12"
    }
}
}
```

**Java**

```
public void readData(JsonReader reader)
{
    floristList = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    try {
        reader.beginObject();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            reader.nextName();
            int id = 0;
            String name = "";
            reader.beginObject();
            while(reader.hasNext()) {
                String field = reader.nextName();
                switch (field) {
                    case "id" :
                        id = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextString());
                        break;
                    case "name" :
                        name = reader.nextString();
                        break;
                    default:
                        reader.skipValue();
                        break;
                }
            }
            reader.endObject();
            floristList.put(id, name);
            reader.skipValue();
        }
        reader.endObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Здесь была лишняя строка в основном цикле, из-за него он опускал указать в самый конец.

`reader.skipValue();`